# How to set the PDF table to full width in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

Thanks for the help in advance. I am exporting a pdf in datatable, the exporting works fine but the table which contains the data inside pdf doesn't takes the full width.Can anyone help me to sort this

Screenshot of issue[image]

```
`/*What i tried*/
 "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 },
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 },
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 },
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 },
 ],`
```

codepen link : https://codepen.io/ANANTHUC/pen/oNyRwXW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33464/export-pdf-with-100-width) discussion on datatables.net, you can add an array of table widths using `*` to mean auto-fit.

In your code, this would be:

```
$("#example").DataTable({ 
  ...
  "buttons": [{
    ...
    customize: function(doc) {
       ...
       doc.content[0].table.widths = ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*' ];
```

as you have 5 columns.  This will then auto-fit those columns and force the page table to 100%.

You can also specify exact/percentage columns widths using the same configuration, eg in your case this appears to work quite well:

```
doc.content[0].table.widths = ['5%','*','10%','10%','10%'];
```

but will obviously depend on your preference.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/puzsh205/